# I want to link the back pack with spine 2

Tags: armature, bones, makehuman

My model data. The back belt is oddly detached from the body.
I want to work with the body.

I added backpack bone but it doesn't work.

How to relate the backpack with the bone.

How to fix this?

I tried these ways below.

I add Auto weight.
Body bone with a backpack.
But, It didn't work.

I add Transfer weight with body objects.
But a backpack becomes broken.

I select backpack, Add modifier, select Armature.
It didn't work.

I asked before, I tried. but I couldn't so I asked again.[image]

[image]

I tried to connect　the horizontal bone of the 7 pack back bones. Brender is good to move but the other software does not work. Become like last of the photo. Maybe it does not effect of bone setting. Export vrm and use 3tene. 3tene.com I want to use it at this software.
[image]

Comment: do you mean like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm20y.gif

Comment: Yes, it is.
I want to move like that.

Comment: Sorry, the mesh is absolutely not suitable for animation. It's a mess & has no order. It has lots of star poles and N-gons which prevent the mesh from deforming well. For example, if you lift the leg, the hip and waist of the character will deform and there is nothing you can do about this. Star poles with more than 5 edges will cause shading issues & the absence of proper edge flow will end in chaos. Check out [What is Retopology & Why Do We Need It?](https://youtu.be/S4YNiImIgPs), [Modeling For Animation](https://youtu.be/01WQlMD7dsk), and [Poly Modeling Bodies](https://youtu.be/6ztn-S0o1DE)

Comment: It was transformed by fbx data.
And I don't have the skill to make of that.
But I think it is different problem about move.
Though, sometimes dissapier the top of white belts.
I want to repair it.
Maybe to use solidify.
It can repair.

Comment: Well, when you export a mesh it gets triangulated. But the tris should be evenly and neatly distributed. A tris is a face is 3 vertices. Your mesh looks really chaotic. -- Does the answer below not work for you? I've tried it and it works for me in Blender. Either make the spline bone the parent (as shown below) -or- use the horizontal bone of the 7 packback bones. Both bones work as parents for the pack back mesh.

Comment: I can todo it.⇒use the horizontal bone of the 7 pack back bones. Brender is good to move but the other software does not work. Become like last of the photo. Maybe it does not effect of bone setting. Export vrm and use 3tene. 3tene.com I want to use it at this software.

Comment: If parent to the bone does not work you can add the weights to the backpack manually. https://imgur.com/a/bU5gGr9  1) select the backpack and remove all vertex groups 2) parent the backpack to the armature with empty groups (make sure you select the armature last =highlighted in orange) 3) select the backpack, goto *Edit* mode, select all vertices, and assign them to the vertex group "J_Bip_C_Chest". That's the spline bone.

Answer (score 0):

in object mode select your back back

[image]

then shift-select the armature

[image]

go to pose mode

[image]

select this bone

[image]

press ctrl-p -> bone

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: I tried to connect this bone. But, I try to make another pose. It does not work well.
I add a photo to the question.

Comment: And, I tried to set the parent with a backpack of seven bones.
It was the same result.

I want to not separate from the body when it moves.